# html5 video on android - unexpected currentTime behavior

Tags: android, html, html5-video

I have a video element on a page I'm loading on an Android tablet. There's a custom play button with the following event listener:

```
play_button.addEventListener("click", function () 
   { video.play(); tap_to_play.innerHTML = ''; 
     video.currentTime = offset; 
     console.log(video.currentTime); }, false);
```

The first time I press the button, it will skip to the incorrect time. The logged currentTime will be 100, even though the video seems to skip to about 1400. If I press the button again when it's already playing, or pause and press the button again, it will go to the correct time. How can I get it to skip to the right location the first time?

Comment: Where is the `offset` defined and how its value is manipulated and what is your understanding of "correct time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "[seekable](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#dom-media-seekable)" TimeRange object to determine if the video file can actually be seeked to that position - otherwise it won't work. Here is a simple function that returns `true` if the desired time is within range:

```
function isSeekable(video, time) {
  if(video.seekable && video.seekable.length>0) { 
    for(var i=0, l=video.seekable.length; i<l; i++) {
      if(time>video.seekable.start(i) && time<video.seekable.end(i)) 
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Check out the jsbin below for an example that works in Android 4.1. It will likely work in 3.1 too, but you will be hard pressed to find a solution that supports 2.3 or below:

http://jsbin.com/udovax/1/edit

(I'd be interested to find a better event to wire it up to - the timeout I used was a quick and ugly hack)